# Google App Engine Launcher Start up Error

Tags: google-app-engine

For the past couple of months I have been error with Google App Engine Launcher. Each time I click on the Icon I keep on getting the same thing. I attach a link that shows a picture of the problem, and another link that shows what in side the error.

Link 1:https://plus.google.com/u/1/115545843446144625696/posts/3VrC8R2vtRD?pid=6166603109008196818&oid=115545843446144625696

Link 2:https://plus.google.com/u/1/115545843446144625696/posts/DHT22BzcGMR?pid=6166675564005054098&oid=11554584344614462569

Comment: Alexander.... why did you copy paste your question? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169035/error-with-google-app-engine-launcher-help)

Answer (score 1):

You should go to your user directory, and delete the Google directory